# Application always launch in Landscape Left

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

In my application, supported orientations are Landscape Right & Landscape Left. Its single screen application. In ViewController I added following code to restrict orientation.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

**My Problem is whenever app launches in Landscape Left. If device position Landscape Right, then app view rotate in 180 degree then app starts working in Landscape Right.**

There is no issue if device position is Landscape Left.

Note: I am testing application on iPod 5.

**EDIT:**

After some observations, If you are supporting only Landscape (i.e Landscape Right & Landscape Left), then you will face this problem. Application will always open in orientation which listed first in plist (In my case that is Landscape Left).

I Closed this issue by removing Landscape Left orientation support. If any one have solution for this please share.

Thanks for help.

Comment: FYI - You only need `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` if you plan to support iOS 5 and earlier.

Comment: @maddy Thanks for information. I am supporting iOS6 and above.

Comment: Check your.plist file and in that see values assigned in "Supported Interface Orientation"

Comment: @Surbhit Thanvi Those are UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft & UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

Comment: Also is your app compatible with both iphone and ipad ? Check Device orientation option in General for both ipad and iphone options

Comment: @Surbhit Thanvi yes. My application is universal app. I made all settings for both. Its working fine on iPad.

Comment: In .plist also their are different options for both iPad and iPhone.

Comment: @Surbhit Thanvi I know that. I made all settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, setting the 'Initial interface orientation' to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft in the plist didn't work, nor did returning it in preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation in the view controller.

What solved this for me is reordering the 'Supported interface orientation' array in the plist to have my desired initial orientation as the first item in the array.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the orientation settings in your **General settings** of the project in XCode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method shouldautotrotatetointerfaceorientation to

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```